# How to Create Tensorflow Session with nvlink GPU

Tags: c++, tensorflow, nvidia

I am trying to run inference with Tensorflow.  I have 2 Quadro GV100's connected via nvlink and another GPU for display on my desktop.

When I create the SessionOptions object, I need to call the following to set which GPU to use:

```
auto options = SessionOptions();
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list(gpuToUse);
```

It does not seem like Tensorflow sees the nvlink'ed GPU's as one, if I were to create a session by specifying only 1 gpu, that seems to negate the benefit of the nvlink and the second GPU.

My question is, is Tensorflow able to take advantage of the nvlink dual GPU setup?

I am using Tensorflow v1.7.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, Tensorflow is able to take advantage of the NVLINK technology. But, as mentioned [here](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/NVLINK-on-RTX-2080-TensorFlow-and-Peer-to-Peer-Performance-with-Linux-1262/?utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=smarter#tensorflow-performance-with-2-rtx-2080-gpus-and-nvlink), most of the algorithms take little benefit from this technology.

There are use-cases where NVLINK bridge might have a **significant** impact. For instance, in some of machine learning applications, parallelism can be gained through data distribution across devices, assuming that the GPU code is optimized to minimize the communication.